# column-count em css quebrando a linha no começo da coluna

Tags: css, html5, css3

Estou usando column-count em CSS para transformar um texto em 3 colunas, até aí tudo bem. O problema é que recebo um texto com essa especificação do MySQL:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
<br>
Nullam ullamcorper efficitur sem id vehicula.<br>
<br>
Aliquam volutpat volutpat velit eget placerat.
```

O problema é que muitas vezes, dependendo do tamanho da tela (é responsivo), a coluna começa já com um `<br>` no topo dela, ficando feio, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para explicar mnelhor, segue meu código:

```css
.coluna{
 width: 90%;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
 text-align: left;
 -webkit-column-count:3;
 -moz-column-count:3;
 column-count:3;   
 -webkit-column-gap:30px;
 -moz-column-gap:30px;
 column-gap:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="coluna">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
<br>
Nullam ullamcorper efficitur sem id vehicula.<br>
<br>
Aliquam volutpat volutpat velit eget placerat.<br>
<br>
Proin molestie purus sit amet rutrum ultrices.<br>
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
<br>
Vivamus sit amet ante quam.<br>
<br>
Quisque fringilla lacus in venenatis ullamcorper.<br>
<br>
In vel odio eget turpis vehicula dapibus.<br>
<br>
Aliquam erat volutpat.<br>
<br>
Quisque et tellus gravida, tristique ante at, dapibus ipsum.
</div>
```

Tem como evitar isso usando CSS? Se não... existe outra solução?

Comment: O texto que aparecerá você recebe do banco de dados?Pode utilizar PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A única forma que encontrei de ajustar isso é usando jQuery.

Eliminei todos os `<br>` e incluí cada linha do texto dentro de um parágrafo `<p>` com margem superior 0. Para isso adicionei o css:

```
.coluna p{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

E o jQuery:

```
var novo_texto = ""; // variável para receber o novo HTML da div
$(".coluna br").remove(); // removo todos os BR da div
var lines = $(".coluna").text().split("\n"); // capturo cada linha da div numa Array separadas por nova linha
$.each(lines, function(n, elem) { // loop
    if(elem != ""){ // aproveito apenas as linhas que possuem texto
        novo_texto += "<p>"+elem+"</p>"; // concateno os resultados dentro de um <p>
    }
});
$(".coluna").html(novo_texto); // Substituo o HTML antigo pelo novo
```

```js
var novo_texto = "";
$(".coluna br").remove();
var lines = $(".coluna").text().split("\n");
$.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
 if(elem != ""){
  novo_texto += "<p>"+elem+"</p>";
 }
});
$(".coluna").html(novo_texto);
```

```css
.coluna{
 width: 90%;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
 text-align: left;
 -webkit-column-count:3;
 -moz-column-count:3;
 column-count:3;   
 -webkit-column-gap:30px;
 -moz-column-gap:30px;
 column-gap:30px;
}

.coluna p{
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coluna">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<br>
<br>
Nullam ullamcorper efficitur sem id vehicula.
<br>
<br>
Aliquam volutpat volutpat velit eget placerat.
<br>
<br>
Proin molestie purus sit amet rutrum ultrices.
<br>
<br>
Lorem. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<br>
<br>
Vivamus sit amet ante quam.
<br>
<br>
Quisque fringilla lacus in venenatis ullamcorper.
<br>
<br>
In vel odio eget turpis vehicula dapibus.
<br>
<br>
Aliquam erat volutpat.
<br>
<br>
Quisque et tellus gravida, tristique ante at, dapibus ipsum.
</div>
```

Comment: Só para explicar porque isso acontece, as colunas no CSS funcionam melhor quando os filhos são blocos, como <p> ou <li>. Já que você está usando apenas <br>, não tem forma de arrumar senão por js.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o PHP.

Passe o texto para uma variável.
E utilize o comando `str_replace` do php, veja o exemplo a baixo:

```
$texto = "Linha de texto longo..."

str_replace("<br>","",$texto);
```

Desta maneira, você remove o `<br>`, e não gera esse problema.

Comment: Mas como ficam as quebras de linhas?

Answer (score 0):

Se você usar assim não resolve seu problema?

```
.coluna br:nth-child(odd){
    display: none;
}
```

Você não precisaria fazer alteração no banco de dados nem precisaria de tanto código.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode trocar os br por p. Testei e deu certo.

```
<div class="coluna">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

<p>
Nullam ullamcorper efficitur sem id vehicula.
</p>
<p>
Aliquam volutpat volutpat velit eget placerat.
</p>
<p>
Proin molestie purus sit amet rutrum ultrices.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
<p>
Vivamus sit amet ante quam.
</p>
<p>
Quisque fringilla lacus in venenatis ullamcorper.
</p>
<p>
In vel odio eget turpis vehicula dapibus.
</p>
<p>
Aliquam erat volutpat.
</p>
<p>
Quisque et tellus gravida, tristique ante at, dapibus ipsum.
</p>
</div>
```